# RegEx for example three comma-separated words

Tags: regex

We are doing lose validation on zipcode of form CITY, ST, ZIP.  These can span countries, so all of the following are valid:

- PITTSBURGH, PA, 15020
- HAMILTON,ONTARIO,L8E 4B3

All I want to validate is that we have three comma-separated words (whitespace is fine).  All of these would be valid:

- foo, bar, baz
- foo,bar,baz123

However these would be invalid because they don't have exactly two commas and three words:

- foo, bar
- boo,bar,baz,bang
- foo, bar,
- foo,bar,baz,

### What I've Tried Unsuccessfully

```
^[\w],[\w],[\w]$

^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*,[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*,[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$  (Doesnt allow sapces)
```

Also just curious - do yall typically allow whitespaces in regex or prefer an application filters whitespace first and then applies the regex?  We can do either.

Comment: I think you want `^\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+){2}$` https://regex101.com/r/N2Q3wh/1

Comment: You can use: `^ *\w+(?: *, *\w+){2} *$`

Comment: Thanks these both seem to work.  Is one preferrable to other?  Can you guys post as answer so I can accept/upvote - if you want the rep?

Comment: @anubhava yours matches to some invalid cases like `boo,bar,baz,bang`

Comment: The advantage of anubhava's pattern is that the spaces are also allowed at the start and at the end of the pattern. @AdamHughes I don't think that matches right? https://regex101.com/r/r6wfdb/1

Comment: I'm sorry I had highlighted that with my mouse and mistakenly thought it was matching!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `^[\w],[\w],[\w]$` that you tried, can be written as `^\w,\w,\w$` and matches 3 times a single word char with a comma in between.

The pattern `^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*,[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*,[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$` matches 3 times repeating 0 or more times any of the listed chars/ranges in the character class with a comma in between.

As the quantifier `*` is 0 or more times, it could possibly also match `,,`

---

If the word chars should be present at all 3 occasions, and there can not be spaces at the start and end:

```
^\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+){2}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `(?:\s*,\s*\w+){2}` Repeat 2 times matching a comma between optional whitspace chars and 1+ word chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XBEApH/1)

**Note** that `\s` can also match a newline. If you want to match spaces only, and the string can also start and end with a space you could use the pattern from @[anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)
 from [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68384084/regex-for-example-three-comma-separated-words#comment120856846_68384084).

Comment: Just curious (no big deal) why is this considered invalid? `foo,bar,baz bang`?  Because `baz bang` is two words?

Comment: @AdamHughes A word character `\w` does not match a space. If you want, you could also optionally repeat a space followed by word characters `^\w+(?:\s+\w+)*(?:\s*,\s*\w+(?:\s+\w+)*){2}$` https://regex101.com/r/j9ebex/1

Comment: Or even `^ *[^,]+(?: *, *[^,]+){2} *$` (assuming input string is in single line)

Comment: Or matching at least 1 word char per part between the comma's `^[^,\n\w]*\w[^,\n]*(?:\s*,[^,\n\w]*\w[^,\n]*){2}$` https://regex101.com/r/pgNzKl/1

Answer (score 0):

Try
 `^\w*\W?,\W?\w*\W?,\W?(\w| ){1,}`

(I tested by your examples)

Comment: Note that it can also match `,, ` as all the quantifiers are optional except for the last one and `\W` matches a non word character, that also be for example `#` instead of a space. The pattern is also missing the `$` anchor to prevent a partial match.

Comment: Thank you, @Thefourthbird, you are right.